# Why is a class A amplifier with load cooler than without load?

Tags: amplifier, power-electronics, power-amplifier

Why is a class A amplifier cooler with load than without load?

In a class A amplifier, the load is directly connected to collector section of transistor. What does 'without load' mean? Is the collector section open-circuited or short-circuited? If it is left open, how does the transistor still remain in active mode? What happens such that power dissipation is less when load is connected then there is no load connected to amplifier?

Comment: *In a class A amplifier the load is directly connected to the collector section of the transistor.* That is not the main characteristic of a [class A amplifier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_amplifier_classes#Class_A). It is no active elements in the signal path getting out of "linear" operation when the output isn't overdriven. (Remember *(electronic) valves*?)

Comment: It would be nice if you showed us the hookup/circuit you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is a class A amplifier cooler with load than without load?

In the so-called *class A amplifier*, the collector-emitter part of a transistor Q and collector resistor Rc are connected in a *voltage divider* configuration (Q acts as R2, and Rc as R1). The load is connected in parallel to Q. Thus it diverts some load current from the common current flowing through Rc; as a result, the collector current through the transistor, the voltage across it, the power dissipated by it and, accordingly, its temperature decrease.

> What does 'without load' mean? Is the collector section open-circuited or short-circuited?

'Without load' means 'open-circuited'.

> If it is left open, how does the transistor still remain in active mode?

The load has a relatively high resistance relative to the output resistance of the amplifier stage. Thus, it relatively weakly changes the mode of the transistor.

Comment: Why are you using [so-called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Words_to_watch#Expressions_of_doubt) "sneer quotes" around the _class A_ expression?

Comment: @pipe, In the English language, aren't they used in the sense of citing a term?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Only when the context makes it clear that it's a citation. Otherwise, the quotes indicate figurative speech - as opposed to literal speech. For example: *He was such a "good father" that they haven't heard from him in years.* vs. *According to a recent news story, "95% of car drivers self-report as above-average".* The latter is a citation, the former is figurative speech - often meaning opposite to the literal meaning.

Comment: @Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica, thanks! And what about the single quotes (in US English)? I use them inside (between) the double quotes.